# Huobi API authentication always fail

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to connect to the Huobi API, but the problem is that the authentication always fails.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+0");

$api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$api_secret="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time());

function url_encode($string){
    return urlencode(utf8_encode($string));
}
    
function http_request($method = 'GET', $url, $headers, $data = null)
{

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);

    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    if ($method == 'DELETE') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    }

    if(!empty($headers)) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $output;
}


$pre_sig = "GET\n

api.huobi.pro\n

/v1/account/accounts\n

AccessKeyId=$api_key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=".url_encode($timestamp);


$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $pre_sig, $api_secret, TRUE));

$url = "https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?AccessKeyId=$api_key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=".url_encode($timestamp)."&Signature=$signature";

$headers[0] = "Content-Type:application/json";
$response = http_request('GET', $url, $headers, $body);
var_dump($response);
```

Returns error:

> "api-signature-not-valid".

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Huobi API auth documentation is [here](https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#authentication). Thank you!

Comment: Could it be that those extra NewLines in your `$pre_sig` are causing a problem

Comment: Great, you're right. Thank you very much!